# Why is my validation accuracy fluctuating between two inverse values?

Tags: neural-networks, computer-vision, python, validation

I am currently going through the FastAI course and to practise, I wanted to code a neural network that classifies the FashionMNIST dataset from scratch.

Lately, I've been running into an issue where I get a consistent validation accuracy score of 0.9 sometimes (afer reinitiating my weights and biases), but occasionally it's stuck at 0.1, and does not go anywhere from there.

[image: when it works]
[image: when it doesn't]

I tried to start again from zero multiple times, but can't figure out the issue. I would very much appreciate any help :)

Below is my code:

```
#hide
!pip install -Uqq fastbook
import fastbook
fastbook.setup_book()

#hide
from fastai.vision.all import *
from fastbook import *

matplotlib.rc('image', cmap='Greys')

import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor, Lambda
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import datasets
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from torch.nn import CrossEntropyLoss

tfms = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize((0.1037,), (0.3081))])

training_data = datasets.FashionMNIST(
    root = 'data',
    train = True,
    download = True,
    transform = tfms,
)

train_x = training_data.data.view(-1, 28*28).float()/255

df = pd.DataFrame(train_x[0].view(28,28))
df.style.set_properties(**{'font-size': '6pt'}).background_gradient('Greys')

target_transform = Lambda(lambda y: torch.zeros(10, dtype=float).scatter_(0, y, value = 1))
train_y = torch.stack([target_transform(y) for y in training_data.targets])

dset = list(zip(train_x, train_y))
dl = DataLoader(dset, batch_size=1024, shuffle=True)

testing_data = datasets.FashionMNIST(
    root='data',
    train= False,
    download= True,
    transform = tfms
)

valid_x = testing_data.data.view(-1, 28*28).float()/255
valid_x.shape

valid_y = torch.stack([target_transform(y) for y in testing_data.targets])
valid_y.shape

valid_dset = list(zip(valid_x, valid_y))
valid_dl = DataLoader(dset, batch_size=1024, shuffle = True)

# Init params

def init_params(size, std=1.0):
  return (torch.randn(size)*std).requires_grad_()

weights = init_params((28*28, 10))
biases = init_params(10, 1)

weights.shape, biases.shape, train_x[0].shape

# Predict

def linear1(xb):
  return xb@weights + biases

# Calculate loss

def cross_entropy_loss(predictions, targets):
  predictions = predictions.softmax(dim=1)
  cross = -targets*torch.log(predictions)
  return cross.sum(1).mean()

cross_entropy_loss(linear1(train_x[0:40]), train_y[0:40])

# Calc grad

def calc_grad(model, xb, yb):
  preds = model(xb)
  loss = cross_entropy_loss(preds, yb)
  loss.backward()

# Train epoch

lr = 10
params = weights, biases

def train_epoch(model, params, lr):
  for xb, yb in dl:
    calc_grad(model, xb, yb)
    for p in params:
      p.data -= p.grad * lr
      p.grad.zero_()

def batch_accuracy(xb, yb):
  preds = xb.softmax(dim=1).round()
  correct = preds.max(1).indices == yb.max(1).indices
  return correct.float().mean()

def validate_epoch(model):
  accs = [batch_accuracy(model(xb), yb) for xb, yb in valid_dl]
  return round(torch.stack(accs).mean().item(), 4)

train_epoch(linear1, params, lr)

validate_epoch(linear1)

for i in range(5):
  train_epoch(linear1, params, lr)
  print(validate_epoch(linear1), end= ' ')

print(linear1(valid_x[0:15]).softmax(dim=1).round().max(1).indices == valid_y[0:15].max(1).indices)
```